# How to make a list of publicly accessable classes in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there an easy way, using Visual Studio, the dotnet SDK, some plugin to either, or anything else to get a list of all the C# classes & interfaces in a project that have a public declaration? I'm aware I can do this using Reflection but was hoping not to have to write any code to do it.

Comment: There are various tools depending on your specific need. Many tools, like [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), work for *assemblies* rather than *projects*.

Comment: if you need to "query" the assembly, I believe the best tool is NDepend. https://www.ndepend.com/

Comment: Visual Studio Classview and change filters to only show public members?